# How to push only some features of development to production?

Tags: git, version-control

```
A
|\
| A
B  \
|  |
|  |
C  B
|  |
|  |
D  F
|  (Production branch)
|
E
|
|
F
|
|
G
(Development)
```

So we want only some changes from development to be pushed and the files have changed drastically in the other commits which aren't supposed to be included. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for specific commits, which might make merging/rebasing a little more compact later.

```
git checkout production
git cherry-pick G
```

Or simply checkout the files you're interested in and make a new commit.

```
git checkout production
git checkout development -- <file>
git commit -m "kludgy import of files from dev branch"
```